# How to deal with a revived potted lemon tree

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, growth, lemons

I did the mistake of leaving my lemon tree outdoor after a rare snow this winter and it lost all leaves. I checked that it was still alive under the bark and since it was, I crossed my finger and waited for spring. Here's the result:

[image]

Now my question is how do I restore it to its former glory. Shall I remove the shoots at the bottom of the tree or does it need them to gather energy? If so, when is the right time for pruning? There is a section on the upper branch which is still alive and generating new shoots too. Shall I remove the other dead branches?

Answer (score 1):

It is doing what it can to survive. Dont give it more trauma.  In a few months time, when you are certain which branches are dead, prune them.